# Referencing System.Configuration

Tags: azure-functions

I tried the following, but it didn't work

```
#r "System.Configuration"
```

This shouldn't be a nuget reference. How should it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sigh, in addition to referencing the assembly for *loading*, had to reference it for C#.

```
using System.Configuration;
```

Beginner mistake.

Comment: Yep, no different from regular C#, but I know it *feels* different :)